# Making Raspbian look like Windows 7

Tags: raspbian

[image][image]My goal is to make Raspbian look like the good old OS, Windows 7. So far, I have already completed:

- Installed the Windows 7 theme
- Installed the mouse cursor theme
- Changed the background to default Windows 7 picture
- Changed the menu bar icon

I have all the default Windows 7 .ico images in my downloads folder, and I am wondering if there is an easy way to install all the icons and replace the default PiXflat file icons. Is there a way to do this? I attempted at making my own theme... but failed miserably. Help is appreciated! I loved the Windows 7 OS, and I heard Linux can look like Windows 7. So this is what I am trying to do

Link to download SegoeUI font from Microsoft: http://b.xfreeservice.com/redir/clickGate.php?u=8otB939m&m=12&p=3b121G4eNI&t=33&splash=0&s=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Ftypography%2Ffont-list%2Fsegoe-ui

Comment: I'm curious about if you find other enthusiasts of MS Windows on a Unix community ;-) Anyway +1.

Comment: There are plenty of guides online of using a custom icon theme. This may help, if you want to change startup: https://raspberrytips.com/pimp-my-raspberry-pi/

Comment: This link may also help https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=147431

Answer (score -1):

You can also install the font Segoe UI to make Raspbian look a little more like Windows.

Comment: Care to explain how?

Comment: I already installed the Segoe UI font. But if you want to install it yourself, follow these steps:

1. Create a .fonts folder in the /home/pi directory.
2. Paste the font in that folder.

The font can also be found in the upload in my original question post.

Comment: @InvictNL I think you should add the steps to install the font in your answer itself.